# Swift/Xcode - Add a currency symbol and commas to UITextField

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextfield

I would like have a method where when a user inputs a number, the textfield will format the number with commas and a currency symbol, in this case I would like the sterling pound symbol - `£`.

Example-

User inputs `30000`, the textfield formats the input to `£30,000`.

I currently do have a method which allows me to do this, however,  I keep getting a decimal/float.

Example- 
User inputs `30000`, the textfield formats the input to `£30,000.00`.

I do not want the `.00` at any time.

How could I fix this issue?

I tried changing from a `float` to an `Int`, but the textfield just resigned instantly.

This is the code I am currently using-

```
extension String {
    func currencyInputFormatting() -> String {

        var number: NSNumber!
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
        formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
        formatter.currencySymbol = "£"
        formatter.numberStyle = .currencyAccounting

        var amountWithPrefix = self

        // remove from String: "$", ".", ","
        let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "[^0-9]", options: .caseInsensitive)
        amountWithPrefix = regex.stringByReplacingMatches(in: amountWithPrefix, options: NSRegularExpression.MatchingOptions(rawValue: 0), range: NSMakeRange(0, self.characters.count), withTemplate: "")

        let double = (amountWithPrefix as NSString).doubleValue
        number = NSNumber(value: (double / 100))

        // if first number is 0 or all numbers were deleted
        guard number != 0 as NSNumber else {
            return ""
        }

        return formatter.string(from: number)!
    }
```

I need one with a currency symbol - `£` and one without.

Could someone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get rid of floating points by setting fraction digits to 0

```
    formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 0
    formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 0
```

And to get the result with Pound sign

```
    formatter.currencySymbol = "£"
```

And to get the result without any sign

```
    formatter.currencySymbol = ""
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I just had to change some code `let double = (amountWithPrefix as NSString).intValue
        number = NSNumber(value: (double / 1))` and now it works! That you so much .